# When I set background from drawable file in android 5, I get an InflateException

Tags: android, xml, exception

This is how i add background in xml file

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle_bluelight"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp">
```

or in button

```
 <Button
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:onClick="*****"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_red"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_white_24dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="*****" />
```

and this is my drawable file rectangle_bluelight

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />

<solid android:color="@color/napravleniyakapuyt2" /> </shape>
```

but i get InflateException can someone show me where is my mistake, i cant find, and then i delete background in xml all works. But in my lollipop its work fine.

Comment: You have invalid drawable file. Android studio must complain and do not even let you compile the project.

Comment: @azizbekian and how to make it work ?

Comment: Add </shape> at the end of your drawable file.

Comment: @Ridcully oh sorry it is in there i make mistake in question

Comment: @Serg your drawable is working.. can you paste stack trace

Comment: @AbhishekSingh i add the stack trace

Comment: @Serg have you checked this `@color/napravleniyakapuyt2` ?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh yes this it is <color name="napravleniyakapuyt2">#004a91</color>

Comment: @Serg its `@drawable/rectangle_red` or `@drawable/rectangle_bluelight` ?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh rectangle_bluelight  i add in question and rectangle_red  its same only with red color

Comment: @Serg your code is working perfectly i tried in my device.. have you checked... you are inflating correct xml? try clean and rebuild also... also try removing `android:onClick="*****"` from your button and check again

Comment: @AbhishekSingh in my android >6 its work perfect but then i test on my tablet 4.4.2 its crashes only help delete android:background(((((

Answer (score 0):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                    Process: ********, PID: 19216
                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{**************}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #120: Error inflating class Button
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #120: Error inflating class Button
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                      at *******.onCreate(******.java:39)
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                                   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0200a6 a=-1 r=0x7f0200a6}
                                                                                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2124)
                                                                                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3579)
                                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:642)
                                                                                      at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:62)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1029)
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1087)
                                                                                      at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:47)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
                                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                                      at ******.onCreate(**********.java:39) 
                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```